# I'll let you know what I ended up with or what I end up with

Tags: grammar

Should one say:

"I'll let you know what I ended up with"

or

"I'll let you know what I end up with"

Which is the correct form to use?

Comment: Even if it is simply a question of determining whether or not the event has already occurred, your question is legitimate and, for what it’s worth, I don’t feel that it deserves the downvotes. The logical notion that you WILL be letting someone know IN THE FUTURE sometime AFTER you know for sure what, if anything, you actually receivED/ “endED up with” IN THE PAST, regardless of whether the event occurred before or after your promise to keep them informed, justifies your confusion and renders your question interesting enough to get my upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is entirely a question of whether you are speaking about an event that has already happened, and you have already *ended up* with something, or whether you are talking about an event yet to happen and you have yet to discover what you might end up with.

For example:

I took part in a quiz show last week and you will be intrigued to know what ***I ended up with***.

I have been invited to take part in an archery contest with very attractive prizes. I will let you know what ***I end up with***.

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is incorrect, but the first one sounds a bit odd and the second one sounds right (at least to my American-English ear).

Comment: Neither one sounds "weird" if used in the correct circumstance. See WS2's answer.